# Android : INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_FEATURE

Tags: android, gps, camera

I got error **INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_FEATURE** while installing my apps in emulator. I am unable to find out the where is the error. My app consists of both GPS & Camera features.
I am not getting where I am wrong. **Is it problem with ANDROID MANIFEST????**
Please Help me out due to this I am unable to deliver my app.Thank you

```
Updated
```

I am getting this error while installing in CONSOLE

```
 [2012-03-16 11:24:50 - DemoCamGPS] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_FEATURE
 [2012-03-16 11:24:50 - DemoCamGPS] Please check logcat output for more details.
 [2012-03-16 11:24:50 - DemoCamGPS] Launch canceled!
```

Here My logcat output details

```
03-16 11:24:49.351: W/PackageManager(59): Unknown permission    android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
03-16 11:24:49.361: W/PackageManager(59): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser  (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x1be45)
03-16 11:24:49.361: W/PackageManager(59): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
03-16 11:24:49.370: W/PackageManager(59): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
03-16 11:24:49.381: W/PackageManager(59): Unknown permission    com.android.providers.im.permission.READ_ONLY in package com.google.android.apps.maps
03-16 11:24:49.381: W/PackageManager(59): Unknown permission com.google.android.pushmessaging.permission.RECEIVE in package com.google.android.apps.maps
```

Here My **ANDROID MANIFEST** file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />    
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />    
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Please find out any wrong uses-feature ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REMOVE BELOW USES FROM YOUR MANIFEST FILE & TRY IT.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
```

THIS HAPPENS COZ YOUR EMULATOR DOES'NT SUPPORT THIS FEATURES, OR TRY THIS FEATURES IT IN HIGHER VERSION API EMULATOR.

Comment: Thanks santhosh its installing now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Can you post your manifest file? You're trying to use a feature( `<uses-feature>` ) the emulator doesn't have. My guess would be the camera.

Debug this by removing each uses-feature line one at a time until it installs without the error. The last line you removed will be the one causing this.

Comment: I have tried that too.. if i remove google uses_features it cant show google map.

Comment: It sounds like you're not linking against the Google API level that you want, as described by Theo. Have you tried it, has it fixed it?

Comment: ya I have fixed that. Actually It was working fine when I was working only with GPS, after that i have integrated camera project in my apps. Then it at all installing .... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Google Maps, geocoding or anything related to that? If so, you should go to Project Properties > Android and link against the Google APIs for your desired API level.

If not using maps, what is the full error trace?

Answer (score 1):

in android manifest add features **android.hardware.screen.landscape** to make app in horizontal view.