# Error message running APK file

Tags: android, macos, apk

I tired to run APK file in my mac machine, when I tried to install the ADB I got an error:

[INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_FEATURE]

Can anyone suggest any solution on this?
Thanks.

Comment: post your manifest...and what device you are using

Comment: Your question is similar to this question.[Android : INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_FEATURE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732037/android-install-failed-missing-feature)

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely because you have declared a feature in your `Manifest` using :

```
<uses-feature />
```

and the device you are installing on does not have that required feature.